# Xamarin Android Distribution

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have run into an issue with distributing my Android app to google play, I have no idea why its happened, but all of the sudden I am no longer able to select "Google play" when choosing distribute, instead I can only select "Ad Hoc"

I am unsure whether this means I need to create a new APK file and sign it with my keystore file (which I have), this has happend to all 3 of my apps, which have been updated and released 30+ times each with no issues, I am a little hesitant with creating a new APK though, because I was of the understanding that is only needed when creating a new app, and not when you want to upload an updated version of the same app.

The "google play" button is simply greyed out as seen on the image.

[image]

So far I've tried "cleaning solution" deleting obj/debug folders and rebuilding, trying the same with an older build of the code, where everything was working (I know because I already distributed that build earlier). I have also tried to reverse to an older version of Visual Studio, just in case the newest version was buggy, also without luck, and also doing a full reinstall/clear of everything Xamarin and Visual studio related.

A small sidenote is that I have also been unable to succesfully get my certificates and download my profiles from my apple account, now while this is not related to the Android release, its just curious that these things happened at the same time.

I am simply unsure whether or not the "Google play" button being greyed out, means the APK is missing a signing, and if so, whether I can just create a new APK sign it with the keystore file I have and everything is back to normal?

Thanks

Comment: can you build an APK and submit to Google manually?

Comment: How about the previous archives? I mean right click the Android project and select "view archives", and check some old archives if can see the google channel

Comment: Thats actually a weird part aswell, can't see any old archives

Comment: @Shaw I have no uploaded a new version of the APK manually to google play, and it seems to work fine, but cannot understand why the "google play" option is just not present in visual studio anymore.

Comment: Sounds like a VS issue then. Try check settings, upgrade or your archive location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem after moving from VS2019 to VS2022.

Here's how I successfully release APKs into Google Play: -

1. Select the APK archive
2. Click the Distribute button down at the bottom
3. Choose Ad Hoc
4. Choose your Signing Identity
5. Click Save As
6. Save (and replace)
7. Enter the signing password
8. Still selected on the correct archive, click the Open Folder button down at the bottom
9. Double-click into subfolder "signed-apks"
10. Go to https://play.google.com/console
11. Choose the App
12. Click the desired Release's menu link on the left
13. Click "Manage track" on the right
14. Click to Create Release
15. Drag and drop the signed APK from file explorer to the web page's App bundles box

Answer (score 6):

Just go in project properties -> *Android Options* and change the *Android Package Format* from apk to bundle

[image: Package format]

As far as I know, play store now only accepts the new optimized aab bundle format.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Updating Visual Studio (or possibly Xamarin) had silently flipped this setting back to apk for some reason.

Comment: Haha, yeah, this actually fixed it, the same had apperently happened to me after updating, what an annoying little thing

Answer (score 0):

@Jason

> can you build an APK and submit to Google manually?

Jasons suggestion worked for me, still can't use Visual studio to distribute to google play, so the manual approach worked, simply not worth it to waste more time trying to figure out why Visual studio isn't doing as it used to.

Quick update:

I reverted back to Visual Studio 2022 v. 17.05

And now my iOS building/archiving works again, its apparently very ill adviced to update your visual studio if you use Xamarin.